# Problems with using QTimer

Tags: qt, timer

I am having a small problem with `QTimer`. Whenever I use `QTimer` it shows me this error

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer();

error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QTimer'
```

So I tried this

```
QTimer timer();
```

Now I got rid of that error but when I use members inside the QTimer it shows me these errors. For example

```
timer.start(1000);
```

or

```
timer->start(1000);
```

> error: request for member 'start' in 'timer', which is of non-class type 'QTimer*()'

I tried to include QTimer but it shows me that there is no such file or directory error.

I am using the Code::Blocks IDE.

Answer (score 11):

Just add

```
#include <QTimer>
```

to the start of your source file. And go back to your first version:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer();
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a QTimer header. If it's not found then you might have your include paths set up wrong. If it's not there, reinstall your Qt SDK.

Your code `QTimer timer();` is wrong. It does not create a QTimer, but you declare a function 'timer', with return type 'QTimer'. It should be `QTimer timer;` although that would most likely give you similar issues if it can't find the header.